# Setup webpage using Windows DNS and Apache on VM

Tags: apache, web, httpd.conf

I have inherited a website to maintain that is hosted on a VM of Fedora/Apache.  The DNS for the website is maintained on a Windows 2000 Server machine.

The current setup has no test site to test changes before deployment.  I have copied the contents of the website on Fedora (found at /pub/customercenter.perceptionistinc.com) to a new directory /pub/customercenterstaging.perceptionistinc.com.

I added the DNS for this new staging site to the Windows server pointing to the same IP address as the live site (192.168.120.11)

On Fedora, I have updated the /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file to include a new virtual host as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

DocumentRoot "/pub/customercenterstaging.perceptionistinc.com"

ServerName customercenterstaging.perceptionistinc.com

</VirtualHost>
```

When I try to access this site all I get is the Fedora Core Test page which is found at /var/www/html/.

I am not familiar with hosting using Apache.  Is there something I need to do/reset/bounce, to get this new addition live?

Thanks for your help,

Brian

Comment: Did you restart apache after editing httpd.conf?

Comment: No, is that required?  If so I will have to wait until after hours as this VM also controls our live site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, any changes in httpd.conf, will be applied only after an apache restart! If it is a production environment, I would suggest testing the config changes on another server, to resolve glitches before you go live with it.

EDIT: There is an option, to reload without restart (no disruption of connections of current clients) 
`/etc/init.d/httpd reload`. See [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-making-changes-config-file-without-restarting/)